# Django form exclude options in select field

Tags: python, django

I have one model that has a ManyToMany Field (let's call it "Options") with another Model

When I create the ModelForm it displays all options.

Is there any way to exclude some option values or to show only some of them?

Here is an example:

models.py

```
class Options (model.Models):
    name = ...
    ...

class Anything (model.Models):
    ...
    options = ManyToManyField(Options)
```

values of "Options" in my DB:

```
["OK", 
"OK_2", 
"NOT_OK", 
"OK_3, 
"NOT_OK_2"]
```

Let's say that **I need to show ONLY the "OK" values** and hide or not to show the "NOT_OK" values.

Is there any way to do this with ModelForms?

Comment: You can limit the items in the ``__init__`` method of your ``ModelForm``. Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16140783/870769. Does it help with your use case?

Comment: this is exactly what I need, post your comment as an answer to give you some points! Thank you! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly can filter the queryset for a foreign key field or m2m on the related model by using a Form or more commonly a ModelForm.

The reason doing this at form level is useful is because that filtering could well be based on business logic which is not applicable in all cases and so allows more flexibility than defining it against the model for example.

While you can do this while defining the form fields it is best to do it once the form has been constructed and so it takes place at runtime and not compile time (I have just experienced a few interesting occasions where this has caused me some issues, however that was an earlier version of Django!)

The following ModelForm would do the job:

```
class AnythingForm(ModelForm):
    options = forms.MultipleChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AnythingForm, self).__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self.fields['options'].queryset = Option.objects.filter({pass in your filters here...})

    class Meta:
        model = Anything
```

Comment: The second `self` is not needed because `super(...)` is getting that role. It should be `super(AnythingForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)`

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the `limit_choices_to` parameter to your `ManyToMany` field:

```
from django.db.models import Q

class Anything (models.Model):
    options = models.ManyToManyField(Options,
                                     limit_choices_to=Q(name__startswith='OK'))
```

In django 1.7 you can even [pass a callable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) in case if list of choices should be changed dynamically.